# Could - was able to

Tags: modal-verbs, could

I know that when people refer to a single past occasion (one-off action) the usage of "was able to" is correct while "could" is not:

**"But when the time came I could pull the trigger".** (this sentence is from a movie)

The matter is that he really pulled the trigger, so I think he should have said:

**"But when the time came I was able to pull the trigger".**

Any explanation?

Comment: The act of discovery may be a single act, but discoveries usually have a lasting impact. So it depends on whether you want to focus on the single event, or on the transformation resulting from it. The first version implies that the ability was there all along, it just needed to be discovered.

Comment: If so, then we can always switch "be able to" to "could". "I was able to play the guitar when she asked me a minute ago" can be replaced with "I could play the guitar when she asked me a minute ago." Do we have different meanings in those two or the same?

Comment: Which film, whoch scene, please? Any chance of a link to a youtube clip?

Comment: Most of us don't discover we can play the guitar. Gaining competence from practice doesn't have the same sense of innateness or revelation.

Comment: The film is "Match point".

Comment: "... when people refer to a single ... past occasion ... while "could" is not" -- source?

Comment: Not that *could* could be used in a difference sense in the context.

Comment: I believe that there is a slight difference of emphasis between 'was able to' and 'could'. They are almost synonomous but 'could' is somewhat more often used for being emotionally rather than physically capable. In the case of firing a gun to shoot another person the emotional capability is more important than the physical capability since physically pulling a trigger is quite easy.

Comment: "while "could" is not" Why is this not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first point is that he *did* say it. Language is what it is, not what some people think it should be.

I agree that I find it a bit odd. But *I found that I could pull the trigger* is to me completely unexceptionable. So I'm not sure why I (or you) have a problem with *I could pull the trigger*.

Comment: Sentences using 'could' this way (OP, not your example)  can be a bit garden-pathy, as 'could' is quite polysemous (unlike 'was able to').

Comment: See also, my second comment at OP.